# how to get dynamic column in dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I blow array

```
[ {"FF15974433790786634518": 1 },
{"FF15974433790786634518": 2 },
{"FF15974433790786634519": 1 }]
```

how to get `["FF15974433790786634518","FF15974433790786634519"]` in dataweave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `map` each item and `pluck` the keys. This gives us an array of arrays, so instead we use `flatMap` (which is equivalent to `flatten(payload map(...`. After getting our flat array of keys, we can `distinctBy` to filter out the duplicates.

Edit: As commented by @machaval below, you can make this even more succinct and easier to read by using `namesOf`, which is a wrapper for pluck.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload flatMap namesOf($) distinctBy($)
```

What all of this is doing when expanded:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
flatten(
    payload map (item, index) -> (
        item pluck ((value, key, index) -> key)
    )
) distinctBy ((item, index) -> item)
```

Comment: Instead of pluck you can use `namesOf(item)`